# align a variable width div in the center

Tags: css, html, alignment

Appologies for a duplicate question, but none of the answers to the other questions seem to fix my problem. I would like to align a `div` in the center of the page. The `div` must only be as wide as the content inside it. It will be used as a modal popup. I have setup a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/PDzNj/11/

The `div` aligns its left side in the middle and not the center of the `div` (which is the desired effect)

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: have your tried setting your css style to margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto? This will position a div with a fixed width in the center of the parent element :)

Comment: @Stephan Fandler - this wouldn't work for a variable-width div, unless you had it as width 0%, and the contents inside it forcing it to become larger, but this can interfere with other stylings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One option is to emulate a table with the `<div>`'s surroundings.

```
<div class='outer'>
    <div class='inner'>
        <div class='thebox'>Contents</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And then use the CSS:

```
div.outer {
    display:table;
    width:100%; //Or however wide you want the container to be
}
div.inner {
    display:table-cell; //This allows the use of vertical-align
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align:center;
    width:100%;
}
div.thebox { //Your variable-width container
    display:inline-block; //Makes it obey text-aligning.
}
```

You can of course add height values as needed. This is neater, CSS wise, than making it relative, or using margins, and also disrupts the surroundings less.

Comment: Note that if you don't need to vertically center, then you don't need `display:table` or `display:table-cell`. For just horizontal centering, `text-align:center` and `display:inline-block` from the above answer are sufficient.